# How to deal with FTP session?

Tags: java, android, ftp

I want to start an FTP session and make sure that it's working well in android . I'm a beginner in FTP so I don't now any thing about FTP. Could u help me and give me a code in android that start an FTP session and get exception if it's not working.

Not working: there is a problem in the network.